# Windows Command line for in do not working from within bat file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch

I have

```
  for /R "C:\path" %f in (_svn) do RMDIR /S /Q "%f"
```

to remove the _svn folders from c:\path and this works if I paste it into the cmd window, but when run from a bat file it says f was not expected at this time.

Permissions? funk-a-tron? wassup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use %%f in .cmd / .bat files to make that work, see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx):

```
Use %variable to carry out 'for' from the command prompt.
Use %%variable to carry out the 'for' command within a batch file
```